# Facebook authentication: remove my app from user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

If a user has signed on to my web app with their Facebook login, how do I remove them again?

The result would be that, if they tried to log in again, then they would be asked if they wanted to add my app along with the permissions, etc.

This is server side so I need the url, something along the lines of

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token="+access_token
```

Edit: clarification above

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The system is explicitly designed in a way so that user do _not_ have to go through the login flow over and over again. What’s your _reason_ for having it another way?

Comment: I don't want it to be this way every time they log in; I just want to be able to do it sometimes. I am testing my app and don't want to create a string of Facebook users to test it with. Plus, if a real user wants to delete themselves from my app.

Comment: Well, you can delete permissions the users have already granted (not the basic permissions given by just logging in to the app though). And real users that use your app afterwards should not be your concern, they can simply remove your app in their FB account settings if they want to.

Comment: So it's not possible? But, Ok, I 'll just remove it from my test user in facebook itself. Didn't realize Icould do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do what I'm trying to do, which is sort of "Start over", your best bet is to just register a new Facebook APP. In other words, delete the current one and get a new APP ID.